# How to programmatically set value of a React Dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code

```
<Dropdown
    id="city"
    placeholder="Select a city"
    options={this.state.cities}
    onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
    />;
```

this will display a dropdown showing the placeholder "Select a city".

What I am trying to do is, if this.state.cities only has one element, to set it as preselected. Otherwise keep showing the placeholder text and all the options underneath.

the library I am using is https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dropdown

thanks

Comment: can you share `this.onChangeHandler` method too?

Comment: provide value prop - conditionally initiated

Comment: the onChangeHandler method does some things when you select an option. I need to preselect the option before the user even click on the control. Actually this is a good point because I didn't think that I need a button to submit the value if preselected.

Comment: @user3174311 Where do you store current Dropdown value, also in state? Because I don't see any value prop of Dropdown in your example.

Also you can initialize selected values in component state, base on cities length, like:

this.state = {
cities: cities; // came from somewhere,
selectedCity: cities.length === 1 ? cities[0] : null
}

But this will work only for component initialization, so if you fetch cities from backend, you can do something like:

<Dropdown
    id="city"
value={this.state.selectedValue || (this.state.cities.length === 1? this.state.cities[0] : null)} />

Comment: You failed to specify the library that you are using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dropdown), the `Dropdown` component takes a `value` prop.

```
import Dropdown from 'react-dropdown'
import 'react-dropdown/style.css'

class App extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
     super();
      this.state={
        cities: ["New York", "San Francisco", "Seattle", "Washington DC"],
        selectedCity: ""
      }
   }

   handleSelectCity = (option)=> {
      const selectedCity = option.value
      this.setState({selectedCity});
   }

   render() {
      const {selectedCity, cities} = this.state;

      return (
        <Dropdown 
          options={cities} 
          onChange={this.handleSelectCity} 
          value={selectedCity} 
          placeholder="Select an option" 
        />
      )
   }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: what if cities: ["New York"], only?

Comment: You will have only one option to select which is `New York`

Comment: great but my question was how to have it preselected.

Comment: to preselect "New York", simply set `selectedCity` to "New York" in the `this.state` object. 

```this.state={
       cities: ["New York", "San Francisco", "Seattle", "Washington DC"],
       selectedCity: "New York"
}```

You may play around with my code

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

In the Dropdown component you can do something like this

```
{(this.props.options.length > 1) ? <option>{this.props.placeholder}</option>: null}
```

Browser will automatically select the first option in the list.